# vSphere 5.5: Binding VMs to HBA cards on the host

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, vmware-vsphere, hba

I am setting up a lab and wanted to be sure the following makes sense\is possible:

One server running vsphere 5.5 with two fiber HBAs
2 Windows 2012 Hyper-V VMs each bound to an HBA

I'm using vSphere because it supports nested visualization, but I'm really setting up this lab to test out hyper-v and live migrations.

Will I easily be able to bind each VM to a physical HBA on the host or are there any caveats I should know about?

*edit: Sorry this question was vague, I have not used vSphere before nor worked with HBA cards in a virtual setup like this.

I located the [HBA's drivers for vSphere](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=DT-ESXI55-EMULEX-LPFC-1005758&productId=353) and [for windows](http://www.emulex.com/downloads/emulex/drivers/windows/windows-server-2012-r2/drivers/).

Now my question is this: Do I install the vSphere drivers on the host and make the HBA's available to the guests somehow OR should I use PCI pass-through and install the HBA drivers on the Windows guests?

The host is a Dell T610 which I'm pretty sure supports IOMMU. I think PCI pass-through is the only way to achieve what I want- is this correct?

Comment: I think you can do this with PCI passthrough.

Comment: is there a reason you're not just using shared vmdks between the two hyper-v vms? Would give the same functionality.

Comment: Possibly, but I have an actual SAN device I am planning on connecting this server to. I want to test serving up LUNs from the SAN directly to the Hyper-V VMs. I want to use the VMs like they are two physical servers attached via HBAs to a SAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot about this question and arrived at a solution some time ago.

Turns out the server did not support PCI pass-through.

But I served up LUNS to the host and used shared vmdks as suggested, which worked well enough.

Unfortunately I won't be able to play with stuff like Server 2012's native MPIO offering, but I'm limited by the hardware.